# email intent onactivity result display alertDialog on Result_Ok

Tags: java, android

Code Here

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {   
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());    

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) return;
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            alertDialogBuilder    
                    .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_result_request, null))
                    .setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_result_request);
            alertDialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.PauseDialogAnimation);  
    }
```

Comment: i cant get it to display the alertDialog on result_ok

Comment: Make sure your code is executing which lies under your RESULT_OK condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code in your `onActivityResult` method like below  code  and add if condition that matches with your result code.

```
 // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
{  
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
// check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
  if(requestCode==2)  
    {  
     //Do your task here 
    }  
}
```

Comment: the onactivityresult is for an email intent and it always returns the same request and result code whether you complete it or cancel it so you cant test against different result. I decided to not use email intent but rather javamail api and send the email from within the app. But thanks for the help :)